# Add/Remove class to child component div from parent component using refs

Tags: reactjs, ref

I want to add/remove class of child component's outer div from Parent Component on click of sidebar menu  button(in parent component).
On click of SidNav toggle button ,expand the nav and add class to the Child Component's outer div so that the content gets pushed to right.

Tried : passing ref as props -  I am getting the reference but actual child dom doesnot update when class applied from Parent Component.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Snippet :

Parent Component :

```
return(<Child ref={this.ref} navigation={navigation} searchParams={parsedQuery} />)
```

child component :

```
function render() {
  const { navigation, classlg2, ref } = this.props;
  return (
    <div className="bx--grid page-content--wrapper">
      <div className="bx--row">
        <div
          ref={ref}
          className={
            navigation.length > 0
              ? "bx--col-lg-2 bx--col-lg-14"
              : "bx--col-lg-16"
          }
        >
          {routeComponentsElements}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`bx--col-lg-2` is the class that I need to add and remove on toggle of `SideNav`.

If states are used to handle the className,then the content rerenders..
Example : there is ajax call in child component, when menubutton is clicked it rerenders the page going back to its home page.

Comment: can you include your codes please

Comment: can you add a stackblitz sample or code block

Comment: I think this is an XY problem. Why do you need to use refs in this case? Just pass a boolean "isExpanded" to the child and conditionally apply the style class.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

Parent component

```
this.state = {
  childClass: false
}

toggleChildClass = () => {
  this.setState(prevState =>({
    childClass: !prevstate.childClass
  }))
}

render(){
  const {childClass} = this.state;

  return(
    <>
        <button onClick={this.toggleChildClass}>Toggle Class</button>
        <ChildComponent childClass={childClass} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Child Component

```
render(){ 
    const { childClass } = this.props;
    return(
        <div 
            className={childClass ? "bx--col-lg-2 bx--col-lg-14" 
                                  : 'bx--col-lg-16'}> 
          {routeComponentsElements} 
        </div>
     )
 }
```